# Laravel 5.5 Testing JSON header doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.5, laravel-request, laravel-response

I have a problem in testing Laravel 5.5. I need to send a Bearer Token in TEST HEADER, but doesn't work

```
public function testAuthCheckinvalidToken()
    {
        $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token,
        ])->json('GET', 'auth/check');
    ...
    }
```

When I dd($response), only the default HEADERS is set:

```
#headers: array:5 [
            "cache-control" => array:1 [
              0 => "no-cache, private"
            ]
            "date" => array:1 [
              0 => "Tue, 21 Nov 2017 18:48:27 GMT"
            ]
            "content-type" => array:1 [
              0 => "application/json"
            ]
            "x-ratelimit-limit" => array:1 [
              0 => 60
            ]
            "x-ratelimit-remaining" => array:1 [
              0 => 59
            ]
          ]
```

My HEADERS doesn't appear. 
I think that I am right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The headers you set here are for request obviously, for Response you are getting headers from your Laravel application so obviously you won't see the headers you set for your request.

If you want to see headers you set here, you should run `dd($request);` in your app and not in tests.

**EDIT**

To confirm that headers are passed to application the whole testing code:

**tests/Feafure/ExampleTest.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . 'abc',
        ])->json('GET', 'auth/check');
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('auth/check', function() {
   dd(request()->headers); 
});
```

so when I now run test:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

result is:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#49   #headers: array:8 [
    "host" => array:1 [
      0 => "localhost"
    ]
    "user-agent" => array:1 [
      0 => "Symfony/3.X"
    ]
    "accept" => array:1 [
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "accept-language" => array:1 [
      0 => "en-us,en;q=0.5"
    ]
    "accept-charset" => array:1 [
      0 => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    ]
    "content-type" => array:1 [
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "authorization" => array:1 [
      0 => "Bearer abc"
    ]
    "content-length" => array:1 [
      0 => 2
    ]   ]   #cacheControl: [] }
```

so as you see headers from test are passed to application

Comment: Actually my headers have not been sent, so, my request fails

Comment: @FernandoHeriqueRubimPioli Look at my edit, everything is working as expected

Comment: adding to the answer I would like to say that for POST requests you can send in data using ->json('POST', 'url', $dataAsArray); 
you can use json_decode('jsonString',true) to convert Json to Array

Comment: if someone needs the way to get each atributtes: $request->headers->get('user-agent')

Answer (score 0):

Please check you Auth guard
Maybe your auth quard cache request and than use info from previous request